# CSS SVG align vertical middle with Label

Tags: css, svg

Hi I have the following code where I need to vertical align the SVG with the label.

```css
g {
  fill: blue;
  fill-rule: evenodd;
}

#firstdiv:hover {
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: #dcd9d9;
  padding-top: 6px;
  height: 35px;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

#svgcontainer {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div id='firstdiv'>
  <div id='svgcontainer'>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="22" height="22" viewBox="0 0 22 22">
        <defs>
            <path id="a" d="M11 11a3.666 3.666 0 0 0 3.667-3.667A3.666 3.666 0 0 0 11 3.667a3.666 3.666 0 0 0-3.667 3.666A3.666 3.666 0 0 0 11 11zm0 1.833c-2.447 0-7.333 1.229-7.333 3.667v1.833h14.666V16.5c0-2.438-4.885-3.667-7.333-3.667z"/>
        </defs>
        <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
            <mask id="b" fill="#fff">
                <use xlink:href="#a"/>
            </mask>
            <g fill="#000" fill-opacity=".54" mask="url(#b)">
                <path d="M0 0h22v22H0z"/>
            </g>
        </g>
    </svg>

  </div>
  Test
</div>
```

And when you hover nothing has to moved because right now when hover because the SVG is not vertically aligned to the middle when hover there is a move of the elements.

https://jsfiddle.net/164seo3g/1/

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few pointers,

1. usually hover should change only the relevant css properties, it should not change layout & stuff, so, what I did is to split styles, without hover contains all the props that related to layout, hover, contains only the change.
2. You can use `vertical-align: middle` on item that has **siblings**, your svg was inside a container, and therefore this wasn't worked.

```css
g {
  fill: blue;
  fill-rule: evenodd;
}

#firstdiv {
  border-radius: 25px;
  line-height: 35px;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

#firstdiv:hover {
  background: #dcd9d9;
}

#svgcontainer {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id='firstdiv'>

  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="22" height="22" viewBox="0 0 22 22" id='svgcontainer'>
        <defs>
            <path id="a" d="M11 11a3.666 3.666 0 0 0 3.667-3.667A3.666 3.666 0 0 0 11 3.667a3.666 3.666 0 0 0-3.667 3.666A3.666 3.666 0 0 0 11 11zm0 1.833c-2.447 0-7.333 1.229-7.333 3.667v1.833h14.666V16.5c0-2.438-4.885-3.667-7.333-3.667z"/>
        </defs>
        <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
            <mask id="b" fill="#fff">
                <use xlink:href="#a"/>
            </mask>
            <g fill="#000" fill-opacity=".54" mask="url(#b)">
                <path d="M0 0h22v22H0z"/>
            </g>
        </g>
    </svg> Test
</div>
```